# Make a submit <button> work outside of <form> block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to place a submit `<button>` outside of a `<form>` block. How to make a submit  that can execute `method="post" action="/order/setup"` from form block`?

```
<form id="order-form" role="form" method="post" action="/order/setup">
 <input type="text name="first_name" />
</form>

<div class="details-section-button row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-dark right shadow arrow">Next <i class="icn btn-right-arrow"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: You can submit forms in javascript...

Comment: This is not a duplicate, this is <button> submit question

Comment: How does your context differ from the duplicate? I don't see how input vs. button would change the answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In browsers that support [the new `form` attribute from HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fae-form):

```
<button form="order-form">…</button>
```

… but don't. Adjust your design so that form controls are inside the form they are associated with. It doesn't make semantic sense to split them up.

Comment: what does order-form do? does it push inside the form?

Comment: @C-linkNepal — It's the id of the form.

Comment: Interesting, does it work on IE9+?

Comment: I haven't found a browser compatibility list for it yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form#order-form").submit();
```

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: I don't think JQuery is really necessary for something as simple as this. Someone flagged this as not an answer though, but I have to disagree with them: this is definitely an attempt at an answer, even if it's not the best answer. To whoever flagged this: if you really don't like it so much that you must do something, downvote it, don't flag it. Marking this as "Looks OK".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, giving your submit button an id of `submitButton`:

```
<div class="details-section-button row">
   <button id="submitButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-dark right shadow arrow">
      Next 
      <i class="icn btn-right-arrow"></i>
   </button>
</div>
```

Then with jQuery:

```
$("#submitButton").on("click", function () {
   $("form#order-form").submit();
});
```